# SQLITE One-To-One to same entity

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, android-sqlite, sql-insert, sqlite-net

I've been stuck for this whole day on one thing. Im using SQLITE to build a local database for my xamarin app and I wanted to insert some data as follow :

```
[Table("Localisations")]
    public class Localisation
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public  int Id { get; set; }

        public  string Label{ get; set; }
      

        [ForeignKey(typeof(Adresse))]
        public  int AdresseId { get; set; }

        [OneToOne]
        public  Adresse? Adresse { get; set; }


        [ForeignKey(typeof(Localisation))]
        public int ParentId{ get; set; }

        [OneToOne]
        public Localisation? Parent{ get; set; }
        
    }
```

As you can see, I have a One-To-One on the same entity. But when inserting, both the  `ParentId`  and the `Parent` gets inserted wrong, and therefor when it comes to getting the data from the database, the results are inexplicable, most of time the parent is the same as the main object, while the ParentId equals to some other Id.

I tried to insert one row each from a list of localisations just for debuging purposes, here is a snippet (for debuging)

```
foreach (var l in localisations)
{
  var adresse = sqliteConnection.Update(l.Adresse);
  if (adresse == 0)
    sqliteConnection.Insert(l.Adresse);


  var parent= sqliteConnection.Update(l.Parent);
  if (parent == 0 && l.Parent!= null)
     sqliteConnection.Insert(l.Parent);

  sqliteConnection.InsertWithChildren(l);
  var rslt = sqliteConnection.GetWithChildren<Localisation>(l.Id);
}
```

**UPDATE**
I've been able to understand what it is doing. It seems that when trying to get the parent, it goes looking for the one who have the same ParentId instead of getting the one who have the same Id.

For Exemple :

```
Localisation A = new Localisation { Id = 1, Label = "France", ParentId = null, Parent = null}; 

Localisation B = new Localisation { Id = 2, Label = "Paris", ParentId = 1, Parent = A};
```

So what it does is that it gets

```
Localisation B = Localisation { Id = 2, Label = "Paris", ParentId = 1, Parent = B};
```

and thats Because B is the one who has a ParentId equals to 1. So instead of looking for the Localisation who has Id = 1, it looks for the Localisation who has ParentId = 1.

the why and the how are still unknown

Thanks

Comment: Can you share some code about inserting data, you said that ParentId equals to some other Id, please share some data  for Localisation table.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT, Okey, I've been able to understand what it is doing. It seems that when trying to get the parent, it goes looking for the one who have the same ParentId instead of getting the one who have the same Id. I will update my post

Comment: It seems that you solve your problem now?